# Is it possible to change the size of icons in the indicator applet?

Tags: indicator, gnome-panel, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indicator Applet Icons Spacing Too Large](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46187/indicator-applet-icons-spacing-too-large)

The width of the icons in the gnome panel indicator applet is taking up too much space. Is it possible to specify the width of the icons in some configuration file so that the icons do not take extra space ?