# Indicator Applet Icons Spacing Too Large

Tags: indicator, applet

I'm using Gnome Classic , Ubuntu 11.04.  The icon spacing for the indicator applet icons is just too large. Is it me or has this  happened to someone else? Has anyone found a fix?
Back in 10.10, a ppa , ppa:m0sia i think, had packages that corrected this design sore. There are no packages there for Natty atm.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, GConf doesn't have any entries for indicator applet spacing and currently m0sia's PPA - as you've noticed - is only for Maverick.
You could tick yourself off at the [**100 Papercuts bug**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/527267) as affected.

Maybe, like Rocko (Post #4), you could agree with him and suggest to use GConf entries?

Fingers crossed that they at least enable a gconf-editor setting for applet spacing in Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot.

Also, if you're keen... you can [**try out this guide**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/527267/comments/88) to compiling your own indicator-applet with a fix for spacing.

**Be warned though**, the same person who posted the how to, [**also noted**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/527267/comments/89):

> For other themes, where the patch only represents an improvement for Indicator Applet and not a fix, the portion of the space/gap that is **NOT** eliminated, is necessary to retain good readability for Indicator Applet Application Menu.

Comment: I follow the guide mentioned above and indeed that it turn out also reducing indicator-appmenu that make it hard to read and almost overlapping, then I try to reinstall deb package of indicator-applet-appmenu, indicator-application & indicator-appmenu and solved my expectation, now I have indicator-applet-complete with reduce spacing and also readable indicator-appmenu on the left as before applying the patch above, thank you for providing the patch