# Change spacing of icons in Indicator Applet Complete, preferably by editing a config file?

Tags: configuration, indicator, icons

### Changing icon spacing within Application Indicator Complete.

If at all possible, I'd like to space them with about 1-3px between each one.

[image]

https://launchpad.net/indicator-applet [Website]

I'm using 12.04, and in GNOME Classic (No Effects). I'm working from a netbook (1024x600), and am trying to fit everything into one panel for the sake of screen conservation. Ironically, my *netbook* is often without reliable *net access*, and so a way to simply edit a config file or the like would be ideal, as opposed to downloading patches, modified packages, etc., but anything would be helpful. Even pointing me in the direction of how to start rebuilding the indicator to meet my needs (if need-be) would be welcome.

Does anyone know of a method that would serve my purpose?

EDIT: I've downloaded v0.4.93 from the site mentioned above, and took a look inside the archive. Couldn't find anything clearly alluding to object placement/size and such. Maybe just a pointer on where to find those params would do?

EDIT 2: Some more info on my WM/DE: I'm pretty sure GNOME classic is gtk2 not gtk3, and equally sure my windows manager is metacity, as opposed to compiz. "equally sure" meaning i could be horribly wrong, but when I edit the metacity css file for my theme (which ive switched to "Adawaita"), it takes effect after logout/login. My inability to modify the spacing persists. Im gonna see if i can contact someone involved in its dev to get their input, will post results here if fruitful.

Comment: Is this answer any help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel/76884#76884

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks, and at first glance I thought it would help, but it seems those are individual applets, and different from the "Indicator Applet Complete" in that they are added to the panel seperately. I could be wrong, as I wasnt around for that ver. of Ubuntu. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/46187/indicator-applet-icons-spacing-too-large

Comment: @fossfreedom it offers some interesting solutions that -failing jasmines' solution below- I may try, but its my understanding that much has changed between Maverick and Precise, in respect to the DE/WM. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
/usr/share/themes/"your theme"/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css
```

Add:

```
-GtkMenuItem-horizontal-padding: 0;
```

To:

```
/* default */
* {
```

The `/* default */` comment is optional, so look for  `* {`.

Comment: this would a great answer if you can add a picture showing (before and after) the change to the css file.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Locate unity.css and gnome-panel.css in your theme folder:

```
/usr/share/themes/"your theme name"/gtk-3.0/apps/
```

try to add the line

```
padding: 0 2px;
```

to certain css selectors, such as .unity-panel or PanelApplet.